# Variable number of return variables in function in Go

Tags: go

I wonder if there is a way to implement a function that behaves similar to map getter: it returns return value as first argument and (optionally assigned) second value `ok` as second argument. So I need function `f` that I can call in following ways:

```
value1 := f(1)
value2, ok := f(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't be done, the only option is to return a pointer and check if it's nil.

```
if v := f(10); v != nil {
     //stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit unobvious after using python that some things can be used in standard library but you can't do them by yourself.

Comment: there are very few things that you can't do in Go yourself, maybe eventually after they finish porting Go to, well, Go, they might allow that, but probably not gonna happen before 1.6 or so if ever.